# Loopback 3 connector soap getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, soap, loopbackjs, getaddrinfo

I just started a new LoopbackJS 3 App and would like to use the soap connector plugin. I'm trying to connect to a Soap server and here's my server/datasource.json config.

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "ppsrSoapDS": {
    "url": "http://schemas.ppsr.gov.au/2016/05/services",
    "name": "ppsrSoapDS",
    "wsdl": "./wsdl/schemas.ppsr.gov.au.2016.05.services.wsdl",
    "remotingEnabled": true,
    "connector": "soap",
    "soapHeaders": [{
      "element": {
        "Security": {
          "UsernameToken": {
            "Username": "<Sampleusername>",
            "Password": "<Samplepassword>"
          }
        }
      },
      "prefix": "wsse",
      "TargetEnvironment" : "Discovery",
      "namespace": "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" ,
      "hostname": "http://schemas.ppsr.gov.au/2016/05/services"
    }],
    "wsdl_options": {
      "soap_version": "SOAP_1_1", 
      "exceptions": true, 
      "trace": 1, 
      "wdsl_local_copy": true
    },
    "security" : {
      "scheme": "WS",
      "username": "<Sampleusername>",
      "password": "<Samplepassword>",
      "passwordType": "PasswordText"
    }
  }
}
```

Using the `ppsrSoapDS` key as datasource I tried to call the API generated using the datasource generator similar to this [procedure](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Connecting-to-SOAP.html)

This is what my API Explorer looks like.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENn5g.png)

Calling the `POST /RegisterOperationsSoap11/Ping` API and providing the following parameters (tested that a single parameter like this works in PHP)

```
{
  "PingRequest": {
    "CustomersRequestMessageId": "20170625100625000000" // sample value
  }
}
```

I received the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND schemas.ppsr.gov.au schemas.ppsr.gov.au:80",
    "code": "ENOTFOUND",
    "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
    "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
    "hostname": "schemas.ppsr.gov.au",
    "host": "schemas.ppsr.gov.au",
    "port": 80,
    "stack": "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND schemas.ppsr.gov.au schemas.ppsr.gov.au:80\n    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)"
  }
}
```

Can anyone here enlighten me with my problem? I'm new to Loopback Soap and any Node Soap. Thank you.